# Binomial regression with categorical explanatory variable

Tags: multiple-regression, binomial-distribution

When doing a multiple binomial regression, is it possible to do the regression with a categorical variable as x at the same time as y is categorical? Most of my x-variables are continuous except for two, while my y-variables is all categorical.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.  The categorical x variables can be converted to indicator variables (0/1).  Many statistical packages will do this conversion for you.